# How computer understand to either represent the original bits or two's complement as value?

Tags: integers, bit-manipulation

## Important note

I know that this question may seem too simple for you scientists; however, here is the best place that I know to post it.

## Question

Suppose we have an `int` with all bits being `0`, except for the last which is `11101000`. How does my computer understand to return its two's complement i.e. `-24` as value and not its original value i.e. `232`?

## Edit: Question Details

I have written the following simple `C++` code which shows unsafe conversions:

```
int main()
{
    double d = 1000;
    {
        int i = d;
        char c = i;
        cout << c;
    }
}
```

The code returns `-24` for `c` while the last byte of `i` which is the value of `c` is `11101000`; Actually `-24` is its two's complement, i.e. `00011000`.

Comment: What makes you think the computer understands that?  Can you give us more context?  Computers don't "understand" anything, so you must be interpreting some behavior you have observed; can you [edit] your question to explain what that is and the basis for your inferences?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signed and unsigned numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/105398/signed-and-unsigned-numbers)

Comment: @D.W. --- Thanks, I edited it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus --- I read only the accepted answer, but it doesn't seem to answer my question.

Comment: @Alish. Is your question "why is the returned value equal to the the integer represented by the last byte of (the representation of) 1000?" or "How does the computer know to print a the characters $\texttt{-24}$ from the byte 11101000? (or, more generally, any number from its representation in two's complement)"

Comment: Reiterating the answers to the question I mention, the computer doesn't know how to treat a value as signed or unsigned. You tell it how you want it to be treated, and the computer obeys.

Comment: @Alish Try replacing 'char c' with 'unsigned char c' and see what the code returns then.